# How do I easily generate a report from python including matplotlib figures and pandas tables

Tags: python, matplotlib, markdown, mpld3

I have a code which calculates a performance report (including text, pandas tables and matplotlib figures). I am looking for away to export this report to a file (html/pdf etc).

I have tried using [pweave](http://mpastell.com/pweave/) but I couldn't make it work properly (the example in the website works but when I try to use it in my code which has classes and functions it seems not to work).  Moreover, pweave doesn't seem to support pandas table.

I am not familiar to [markdown](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown) package but this may be the key together with [mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io/). Can anybody please help me with an example?

Thanks,
Hanan.

Comment: This is probably too broad for a stackoverflow question.

Comment: what would be a good forum for that, than?

Answer (score 0):

from http://buddapie.com/2015/10/31/report-with-matplotlib-tables-and-plots/

The code to produce a whole report is below. For the tables I wrote an algorithm to divide long columns into multiple shorter ones. I am using the Seaborn library as I really like the formatting and it is super easy to set up.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.table as tbl
import seaborn as sns

#range for floats
def frange(x, y, jump):
    while x<=y:
        yield x
        x += jump

#function to return the table, modifying if needed due to size etc
def get_table(ax, ts_list, list_column_labels, list_col_widths, list_col_formats):

    divisor = len(list_col_formats)
    max_length = 19

    #adjusts max length to a min of the length of the timeseries
    max_length = min(max_length, len(ts_list[1]))   

    #creates table array and labels vector
    l = len(ts_list[1])
    l1 = divisor*(l//max_length+1)
    table_array_temp = [get_section(ts_list, i, max_length, l, list_col_formats, divisor) for i in range(l1)]
    table_array = np.array(table_array_temp[0])

    #to fit column width to each column
    table_widths = np.array([list_col_widths[i%divisor] for i in range(l1)])

    for i in range(1,l1):
        #if temp array size doesn't match (it can happen at last rows) adds 0s 
        if len(table_array_temp[i])<max_length:
            table_array_temp[i] = np.concatenate((table_array_temp[i], np.zeros(max_length-len(table_array_temp[i]))))
        table_array = np.vstack((table_array, table_array_temp[i]))

    table_labels = np.array([list_column_labels[i%divisor] for i in range((divisor*(l//max_length+1)))])     

    the_table = ax.table(cellText=np.transpose(table_array), colWidths=table_widths, colLabels=table_labels, loc='center')
    the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    the_table.set_fontsize(6)

    table_props = the_table.properties()
    table_cells = table_props['child_artists']
    for cell in table_cells:
        cell.set_height(0.05)

    return the_table

#formats number
def format(j, format):
    return locale.format(format, j, grouping=True)

#util funciton for dividing values in array
def get_section(list_ts, i, max_length, l, col_formats, d):
    k = i//d
    return [format(j, col_formats[i%d]) for j in list_ts[i%d][k*max_length:min((k+1)*max_length, l)]]

#function to write report
def write_report(list_plots):

    #sets the grid shape
    #tuple for shape of figure
    shape = (3,2)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=shape[0], ncols=shape[1], figsize=(8, 10))

    #lists for changing parameters
    list_labels = [['periods', 'cash flows (m)', 'balance (m)'], ['periods', 'cashflows'], ['periods', 'cash flows']]
    list_titles = ['Simulation 1', 'Simulation 2', 'Simulation 3']

    #where we position the plots and the tables
    axes_plots = [0,2,4]
    axes_tables = [1,3,5]

    #line graphs
    fontsize = 5
    labelsize = 4
    for i in range(len(list_plots)):
        shape = np.array(list_plots[i]).shape
        if len(shape)==2:
            first_ts = list_plots[i][0]
        else:
            first_ts = list_plots[i]
        ax1 = axes.flat[axes_plots[i]]
        ax1.plot(first_ts, c='blue', linewidth=1)
        ax1.set_xlabel(list_labels[i][0], fontsize=fontsize)
        ax1.set_ylabel(list_labels[i][1], fontsize=fontsize)
        ax1.yaxis.label.set_color('blue')
        ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=labelsize)
        ax1.set_title(list_titles[i] , fontsize=7)  

        #if the other axis is relevant, builds it
        if len(shape)==2:
            _test = list_plots[i][1]
            ax2 = ax1.twinx()
            ax2.plot(list_plots[i][1], c='red', linewidth=1)
            ax2.set_ylabel(list_labels[i][2], fontsize=fontsize)
            ax2.yaxis.label.set_color('red')
            ax2.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=labelsize)

    col_widths = [[0.1, 0.095, 0.15], [0.125, 0.11, 0.15], [0.125, 0.13]]
    col_formats = [['%.d', '%.2f', '%.2f'], ['%.d', '%.2f'], ['%.d', '%.2f']]
    col_labels = [['period', 'cf', 'balance'], ['period (y)', 'cf'], ['period (y)', 'cf']]

    #asset simulation tables
    for i in range(len(list_plots)):
        shape = np.array(list_plots[i]).shape
        ax1 = axes.flat[axes_tables[i]]
        #hides the axis etc
        ax1.set_frame_on(False)
        ax1.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax1.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

        if len(shape)==2:
            periods = [k for k in range(len(list_plots[i][0]))]
            t_array = np.array([l for l in [periods, list_plots[i][0], list_plots[i][1]] if l!=None])
        else:
             periods = [k for k in range(len(list_plots[i]))]
             t_array = np.array([l for l in [periods, list_plots[i]] if l!=None])

        #gets the table
        the_table = get_table(ax1, t_array, col_labels[i], col_widths[i], col_formats[i])
        ax1.add_table(the_table)
        ax1.set_title(list_titles[i], fontsize=7)        

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('TestReport', dpi=400)

if __name__=='__main__':

    #example timeseries
    ts1 = [np.arange(50), np.array([np.power(100, -i*0.01) for i in range(50)])]
    ts2 = np.arange(25)
    ts3 = [np.power(i, 3) for i in frange(3, 200, 3.5)]

    write_report([ts1, ts2, ts3])
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, I modified it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

A late answer to your question:

Pweave works well, even with your own classes. Just make sure that the directories of your class files in python's import paths. One way to do this, is adding the directory in the python chunk like this:

````
```python, echo=False
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/python/files/')
import myfile
myfile.myclass...
```
````

Pweave can output to Markdown format (option `-f pandoc`), which you then can process with [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to HTML or via LaTeX to PDF.

As to pandas tables: Convert them in the python chunk to nmarkdown via the [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) package.